# crontab core dump not generated?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, coredump

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on a MicroZed where I'm executing a program that dereferences a null pointer from a crontab script.  Note: I am purposefully trying to create a core dump.

The issue is that when I run the program from the command line the core dump is generated as expected, however when running from the crontab I can't locate the file in any of the expected locations.

Any ideas on whether or not the core dump is actually being created, and if so where?

Comment: Do you see anything in /var/cache/abrt? Also, can you use find to locate it? Also, if you're changing directories inside of your cronjob you might want to check there.

Comment: The version of ubuntu running on this microzed doesn't have a /var/cache/abrt directory.  I've tried running find from the root directory and haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Ah okay, take a look at /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern (could also just be /proc/sys/kernel/core) and it should tell you where it's dumping it. You can also edit that file to send core dumps wherever you want. Also if it's using apport you can probably find the dumps in /var/crash

Comment: This is where it gets strange.  I edited /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern to output the file into /tmp.  Works fine from the command line, however when run from my crontab nothing gets generated there.  Also, I have validated that the crontab is running properly.

Answer (score 3):

A cronjob runs in a limited environment under `/bin/sh`. What is probably happening is that the default core-dump size is set to zero.
I do believe that this can be seen and configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, however the easiest way to check this is to run the following cronjob :

```
* * * * * ulimit -a > ~/cron.ulimit.txt
```

If the file `~/cron.ulimit.txt` indicates a core-file size of `zero blocks`, then the cron-job will never generate a core file.

You can create a core file by running a wrapper script `wrapper` which sets the ulimit for the core-file size. Eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ulimit -c unlimited
/path/to/binary
```

This script can then be ran as a cronjob.